# Java passing String by command line argument missing parts after '/t' and '/n'

Tags: java, newline

I have table structure in HTML. I need to replace `<tr>` with `/n` and `<td>` with '/t' using JavaScript as follows and it works well.

```
var tableData= $("#printdiv table tr").map(function(i) {
    return [$(this).find('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get()];
}).get();

var output = '';
$.each(tableData, function(i, row) {
    $.each(row, function(i, cell) {
        output += cell + '\t';
    })
    output += '\n';
});
```

Check working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/49tkbk91/).

What I am doing is that I am passing this `String` to a Java program using `ActiveXObject`.

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("cmd /c java Test "+output+" ");
```

My Java program is as follows:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String output= "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            output= output+args[i];
        }

        File file = new File("Hello.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
        writer.write(output); 
        writer.flush();
        writer.close(); 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when passing through a command line argument it is only getting the first part of the string up to `/t` and after that nothing is getting written to the file.

How can I avoid that? How do I get the same table format which was mentioned in the Fiddle inside the result text file?

**Note: Do not bother about `ActivexObject`, I am using it intentionally as my application only works in IE.**

I have identified problem is because of `\n`. Because of that it isn't coming. How can I correct this?

Comment: try `shell.run("cmd /c java Test \""+output+"\"");`

Comment: Put the parameter in hyphens e.g. `"cmd /c java Test \""+output+"\""`

Comment: Sorry, but your naming is **horrible**. A StringBuilder is a distinct class of its own (which should actually be used when building strings dynamically), so that name "strBuilder" is very misleading to any java programmer.

Comment: @Getting upto `/n` after nothing

Comment: @ Jägermeister editted please take a look

Comment: @ Sebastian writing into up to first `/n` after that nothing happening.

Comment: Please note that `/n` and `\n` are two very different things. Backslash and forward slash are not the same character.

Comment: @ QPaysTaxes it is a typo error I mean `\n`. I mean new line

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou getting only one line buddy I mean getting only first<tr> after that nothing happening. please take a look

Comment: Updated question please take a look guys

Comment: if the argument you are passing contains white spaces you need to wrap it with double quotes "